# Magento 2.3.3 The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, readiness-check

I want to install a plugin, but the readiness check gives the next error

Check Component Dependency 
We found conflicting component dependencies.

```
Command "require" failed:
In RemoteFilesystem.php line 559:

The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify
failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>...]
```

I'm using Magento 2.3.3.

Has someone a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What is your environnement and command used?

It seems like a SSL error with the certificate and crypto, check:

- does it break on all call made by composer or only official magento repo?
- is your certificate uptodate?
- do you use any proxy or something changing your ip or dns configuration?
- is there any firewall or antivirus blocking it?

A lot of questions

Comment: I have a Magento webhosting Packet on https://www.versio.uk/magento-hosting. This package normally meets the requirements of Magento. This are my PHP settings: https://ibb.co/bzW7Z2x and I'm using a free SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt

Comment: I also tried with repo.packagist.org, but it gave the same error.

Comment: Is has to be linked with your hosting, did you check with them if they have more log about this error? you need to check the open ssl config, but maybe they restrained the connexions. Might also appears with github https repos.